# How to access an array of dictionaries in Parse API

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I saved an array of dictionaries to Parse, which appears correctly in the `User` class. I can `po user` at a breakpoint and the array shows up properly as one of the properties on the `User`. However, I can't access this data at all, I get a runtime error of `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)`. I'm trying to access the data using `user.userFbFriendsDetail` to save to a local variable. Here is the console result when I `po User`, I can't figure out how to use the `userFBFriendsDetail` array. Thanks a lot for your help!

```
<PFUser: 0x7fe1dd281010, objectId: onHQnYR5d2, localId: (null)> {
    facebookID = xxxxxxx
    fbEmail = xxxxxx
    fbGender = male;
    fbName = "John Doe";
    friendsUsingTheApp =     (
        "<PFUser: 0x7fe1dbd30210, objectId: oqKnKZMN3d, localId: (null)>",
        "<PFUser: 0x7fe1dbd30510, objectId: hUNZvZC4fD, localId: (null)>"
    );
    userFbFriendsDetail =     (
                {
            email = "fake@fake.com";
            facebookID = 1111111111;
            profileImage = "<PFFile: 0x7fe1dfe28422>";
        },
                {
            email = "fake@fake.com";
            facebookID = 222222222222;
            profileImage = "<PFFile: 0x7fe1dbd1ffd1>";
        }
    );
}
```

EDIT: Here is the definition of the `PFUser` class:

```
class User : PFUser {
   override class func initialize() {
      struct Static {
         static var onceToken : dispatch_once_t = 0;
      }
      dispatch_once(&Static.onceToken) {

         self.registerSubclass()
      }
   }

   @NSManaged var gender: String?
   @NSManaged var fbName: String?
   @NSManaged var age: NSNumber?
   @NSManaged var facebookID: String?
   @NSManaged var fbLocale: String?
   @NSManaged var fbTimezone: NSNumber?
   @NSManaged var fbGender: String?
   @NSManaged var fbEmail: String?
   @NSManaged var fbAge: NSNumber?
   @NSManaged var profileImage: PFFile?
   @NSManaged var twitterHandle: String?
   @NSManaged var state: String?
   @NSManaged var birthday: String?
   @NSManaged var friendsUsingTheApp:Array<String>
   @NSManaged var userFbFriendsDetailDict:Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the definition of the PFUser subclass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`userFbFriendsDetailDict` should be of type `Array<Dictionary<String, AnyObject>>`. (And you should access it under that name, not `userFbFriendsDetail`).

Comment: Awesome, I knew it was something stupid. Thanks for taking the time, you are DMan!!